# Is there anyway to restrict device enrolment in Android device policy?

Tags: android, enterprise, android-management-api

We are using Android management API for device management in out Enterprise Mobility Management project. We want to restrict the device count based on the requirement. Once reached the threshold value,We should not allowed to enrol on the enterprise.We can't restrict it in management console. As we are using Android device policy(Device Policy Controller) provided by google, we couldn't restrict it through mobile. Is there anyway to control the device count for a particular enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this via policy. The best way to implement this is through your management console by keeping track of the count of devices using [devices.list API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) and [deleting any valid enrollmentTokens](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.enrollmentTokens/delete) once you have reached the limit.

You can also use the enterprise [SinginDetail](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises#SigninDetail) to display an error message on the signinUrl page with instructions to contact the IT Administrator once the device limit has been reached.